# Android PopupMenu elevation issue

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-menu

When setting the elevation on a PopupMenu in android I get garbage around the menu, as show below.

[image]

My Activity's Theme is setting `popupMenuStyle`:

```
 <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>

   <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupElevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

I am creating this menu in code:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(itemView.getContext(), myButton);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

Does anyone know of a fix?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It was fixed adding in AndroidManifest.xml a theme:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"  android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">
```

then in the theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
</style>
</resources>
```